# The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, web-services

I have an application which opens fine. When I click on any of data displayed in grid of that application (open them in new tab of same browser) , some of the tabs opens and populates data, but some of the tab returns error
Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: This is where you should be using the Debugger.. also it would help it you could show any code that pertains to the current issue that you are having. how would anyone be able to help you in regards to reproducing the same error without seeing any code..?

Comment: I do not get any error on my localhost, this is error i get when i run application which is hosted on server.

Comment: then you probably have to specify the correct domain user\password.. one again can't tell a thing without seeing the code where the specific error is happening..

Comment: There is no error in the code, every endpoint is configured well. svc account for iis has access on SQL server. This  error that i get is for few tabs and not all of them

Comment: sounds like you better go back to using the debugger.. good luck.. and as I have stated earlier.. how is anyone supposed to help you when they can't even see the code in regards to the `Tabs`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Integrated Security (SSPI) and your site is not configured to allow Windows authentication.